# Help me with lyrics sync

Tags: video

I am looking for a program that can help me sync lyrics.
I mean, I have txt with lyrics and I want program to be able to sync them with just press and release of any button. At end I want program to export to srt ar any other popular subtitle format.

Comment: please don't ask duplicate questions. Read [ask] and our [about] page for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

**MX** player allows the lyrics (*.srt file) to be synchronized in mobile using its app .(subtitle->synchronization)
For laptop, you can use **VLC** player.